# How to find matched parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010

Suppose I use Visual Studio 2010 to write jquery code, there are a lot of parenthesises.
I may miss one or more parenthesises. What i sthe quick way to find or check matchness of parenthesis?

Comment: Start by creating the closing brace every time you make an opening brace. There's no real reason to wait till you're done writing the inner part of the code block to create the closing one. Some editors even do that for you.

Comment: Write good code to begin with. Stop the the indentation craze. Create functions when they're needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Assist which has Highlight Matching {} and ()

http://www.wholetomato.com/features/feature-code-correction.asp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DavidPostill - There really isn't much to add from the link.  It is a list of features, and the answer already contains the relevant point.  The link doesn't contain additional instructions on usage or the like.